# slickgrid formatter and virtual scrolling resetting form

Tags: slickgrid, formatter

```
function linkFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    var cell = "";
    cell += '<input type="checkbox" id="cb' + dataContext['id'] + '" name="cb' + dataContext['id'] + '" value="' + dataContext['id'] + '" ' + (dataContext['Reviewer'] == 'Unassigned' ? 'class="unassignedLoan"' : "") + '> ';
    cell += '<a href="LoanEdit.aspx?loanid=' + dataContext['id'] + '">' + value + '</a>';
    return cell;
};
```

I have this formatter function with a `dataView`.  The `checkbox` the formatter creates gets reset when the user scrolls that row out of view and clicks on a different cell.  I think the virtual scrolling is re rendering that cell with the formatter so it loses the values of the `checkbox`.  Does anyone have a suggestion to get around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On scrolling or sorting, the grid DOM is created again. So the initial values get reset.
You have to save the values (e.g. id's of the checkboxes checked) in an array and set it again on scroll and sort event.

Do it like this...

```
grid.onScroll.subscribe(function(e) {
            grid.invalidate();
            grid.render();

            var $canvas = $(grid.getCanvasNode()), $allRows = $canvas
                    .find('.slick-row');

            $($allRows).each(function() {
                if(this row's checkbox is in selectedRowId){
                                       set checkbox property to checked;
                                     }
            });

        });
grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e) {
            grid.invalidate();
            grid.render();

            var $canvas = $(grid.getCanvasNode()), $allRows = $canvas
                    .find('.slick-row');

            $($allRows).each(function() {
                if(this row's checkbox is in selectedRowId){
                                       set checkbox property to checked;
                                     }
            });

        });
```